# cannot implement concurrent animation in applet

Tags: java, multithreading, applet

this z my first hand experience with applet animation. I have created a small game in which on the upper part of the applet a train of blocks has to keep moving and on d bottom derz a block dat has to hit a bullet to one of d block of d moving train.The problem is dat whenever I press the directional up key,the bullet starts going up but the train stops(though i know why its happening).But I need both bullet and train to move (according to thier own speeds).....herz d code:

```
//<applet code=abyss.java width=500 height=500></applet>
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class abyss extends Applet implements Runnable,KeyListener{
int l,i=0,n,c,ct=450,cl=225,y,f,bl,bw,fr;
Thread v=null;
public void init() {
setBackground(Color.black);
addKeyListener(this);
                      }
public void start() {
       v=new Thread(this);
       v.start();
                         }
public void run() {
try{
while(true) {
if(y==1) {
bl=cl+25;
bw=4;
f=446;
while(f>41)
 {
repaint(bl,f,bw,bw);
f--;
v.sleep(5);
    }
y=0;
bw=0;
          }
System.out.println("in thread");
repaint(); 
v.sleep(1000);
i=i+40; 
c=1; 
System.out.println("after sleep");
n=i/40;              

 } 

  }
catch(Exception e){}

                      }


public void paint(Graphics g) {
g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
g.fillRect(0,200,30,300);
g.fillRect(470,200,30,300);
g.fillRect(0,470,500,30);
g.setColor(Color.blue);
g.fillRect(cl,ct,50,20);
setBackground(Color.black);
System.out.println("in paint()");
for(int j=n;j>=0;j--)
{  l=j*40;
if((c%2)==0)
{g.setColor(Color.orange);
g.fillRect(l,0,50,40);}
else
{g.setColor(Color.cyan);
g.fillRect(l,0,50,40);}
c++;
System.out.println("in for"); 
}

g.setColor(Color.yellow);
g.fillOval(bl,f,bw,bw);                            
                                           }

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
cl=cl-10;}
if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
cl=cl+10;}
if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP){
y= 1;}
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
public void stop() {
try{wait();}
catch(Exception e) {}
}
public void destroy() {}
}
```

what i need is either to use two separate paint() for same applet or two separate run() for same applet........but i can find neither's implementation.PLz help ASAP

Comment: Use proper English to make your question readable. "herz d code" is not English. If you want help ASAP, you'd better make your question easy to read and understand by the free answerers. Also indent your code, while you're at it.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `run` method:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        int trainDelay = 0;

        while (true) {
            if (y == 1) {
                if (f > 41 == false) {
                    bl = cl + 25;
                    bw = 4;
                    f = 446;
                }
                if (f > 41) {
                    repaint(bl, f, bw, bw + 1);
                    if (--f > 41 == false) {
                        y = 0;
                        bw = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (trainDelay <= 0) {
                repaint();
                i = i + 40;
                c = 1;
                n = i / 40;
                trainDelay = 200;
            }
            Thread.sleep(5);
            trainDelay--;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```